# Autohotkey - SetTitleMatchMode not working

Tags: autohotkey

can someone help me with a simple question? I'm trying to get my IfWinExist working. I want the script below to only apply to windows with the title "Internet Download Manager", but not "Internet Download Manager - Configuration". At the moment, the script closes both of those windows.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 1 // have tried setting this to 3 as well but didn't work

SetTimer, CloseIDMRegistrationPopup2, 5000

CloseIDMRegistrationPopup2:
IfWinExist, Internet Download Manager
{
    Winget, annoyed, ID, Internet Download Manager
    WinActivate, ahk_id %annoyed%
    WinShow, ahk_id %annoyed%
    Sleep, 1000
    WinClose, ahk_id %annoyed%
    ;Send, {ESC}
}
return
```

Comment: Use "SetTitleMatchMode, 3" (A window's title must exactly match WinTitle to be a match)  https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

Comment: If the window is hidden, you have to add **DetectHiddenWindows, On**. If the script doesn't contain any hotkeys, add **#Persistent** on top.

Answer (score 2):

According to

http://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

> SetTitleMatchMode, MatchMode
>
> One of the following digits or the word RegEx:
>
> 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
>   2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
>   3: A window's title must exactly match WinTitle to be a match.

So you should use:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that too but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually, I just reloaded my script and it worked this time. I swear I tried what you suggested like at least 5 times, don't know what happened I must have changed something in the script....